# Entity Framework and grouping by weeks with week start day set

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-5

I need to generate some week summary for an ASP.NET web application using Entity Framework (Code-First approach) with SQL Server.

More of the application is running on the client side and the server just provides access to entities via OData (Breeze.js). Unfortunately Breeze does not support aggregate functions so I have to implement few controller actions server-side, for some more complicated queries needed, such as this one:

```
var query = from r in db.Context.Records
            where r.MeasurementId == measurementId
            group r by SqlFunctions.DatePart("WK", r.Time) into g
            select new
            {
                Time = g.Min(r => r.Time),
                MinImport = g.Min(r => r.Import),
                ...
            };
```

I'm using LINQ rather than context `SqlQuery<T>`, because it returns `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`.

The problem is with date. Records are grouped by week but week starts with sunday by default, however I need it to start from monday. This could be very easily fixed in plain SQL by running:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

But I could not find any solution to this in Entity Framework. Is it possible to run some query right after or during `DbContext` initialization to set the `DATEFIRST`?

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
var query = from r in db.Context.Records
            where r.MeasurementId == measurementId
            group r by SqlFunctions.DatePart("WK", SqlFunctions.DateAdd("Day",-1,r.Time)) into g
            select new
            {
                Time = g.Min(r => r.Time),
                MinImport = g.Min(r => r.Import),
                ...
            };
```

Comment: This should cause Sundays to fall into the previous week, making Mondays the new start of the week.  Oddities might occur during the first week of the year so make sure to check if the code still works in that case.